# Create Embedded ListView Using Visual Studio 2017 Xamarin

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I already create a TabbedPage with 5 Tabs. The 5th Tab is called "More". In this tab, I want to create a embed listview like the image below.

[image: refer image]

May I know how can do it?

Comment: Is anyone can elaborate more ? How to build like the picture above. Thanks.

Comment: Is there anyone can really help to explain how to make it ? Is it using tableview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a TableView in Xamarin.Form.
TableView can be created as below.

```
<TableView Intent="Settings">
    <TableRoot>
        <TableSection Title="Ring">
            <SwitchCell Text="New Voice Mail" />
            <SwitchCell Text="New Mail" On="true" />
        </TableSection>
    </TableRoot>
</TableView>
```

The full example can be found here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/tableview